# Durood Sharif after Asr on Friday authentic?

Tags: hadith, sunnah, salawat

Salam

Is this authentic? I did this maybe two or three times and then stop because I wasn't sure if this was authentic to do
I know it says Abu Huraira said this at the bottom but I saw a video online saying this isn't authentic

[image]

Comment: Wa alaikum salaam. My understanding from what I have studied is that even if an hadith that encourages good deeds for reward like this one is weak, it is permissable to act upon with the hope of attaining its reward. I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but I hope it helps. Allah knows best.

Comment: Thanks for your responce. I saw a video online saying this is a fabrication and in the same video sheikh says the prophet said whoever lies upon me will take his seat in the hell fire which got me a little worried

Comment: Yes, I have heard that too. That's why one must be careful when narrating hadeeth. If you're not sure of the exact wording you should always make that clear.

Comment: thank you brother may allah bless you i'm trying to learn more

Comment: https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/307192/invoking-blessings-upon-the-prophet-sallallaahu-alayhi-wa-sallam-eighty-times-on-friday

Comment: @Umh Thanks for that!